# Change the Facebook page owner from a business page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Agency that I had hired to manage my Facebook page has gone rogue and is not handing over the ownership of the page. I am still the admin can I get the ownership back without him having to sanction it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are an **Admin** of the page you can remove other people from their roles and then you will be the only owner of the page.

From the [Facebook help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/187316341316631):

> **Remove Someone Who Has a Role**
>   If you're an admin:
>
> 1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page.
> 2. Click **Page Roles** in the left column.
> 3. Click **Edit** next to the person you want to remove, and then click **Remove**.
> 4. Click **Confirm**. You may need to enter your password.
>
> You can always remove yourself from a Page, but if you're the Page's only admin, you'll need to add another admin first.

Know more about [What are the different Page roles and what can they do?](https://www.facebook.com/help/323502271070625/)